# Having an issue with configuring json data, and a bit stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I have json data from an express get request that uses a select statement to retrieve number of rows in a table. I'm trying to configure out how to configure the json data that looks like this:

```
{
  "metaData": [
    {
      "name": "COUNT(*)"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "COUNT(*)": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to configure it to something like this:

```
{
     "id":1,
     "name":"Incidents",
     "type":total
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually very easy to use JSON in JS, because JSON is literally how we represent JS objects (**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation) therefore we can easily read from JSON and create our very own JSON.

In order to do this we first need to access the total from the returned JSON, by accessing `COUNT(*)` from the first item of `rows`. We do this using  `req.body["rows"][0]["COUNT(*)"]` which we then store in the variable `total`.

We then layout our own object pretty much as it appears in standard JSON, making it access the total from the variable `total` which we just created. We then use `console.log` to display to the result.

```
// I presume req.body is the data returned from express
let total = req.body["rows"][0]["COUNT(*)"];
let newJSON = {
   "id": 1, // Or whatever ID you want
   "name": "Incidents",
   "type": total,
};
console.log(newJSON);
```

And finally if you want to turn it into a string we can use `JSON.stringify`:

```
let jsonString = JSON.stringify(newJSON);
```

Comment: I think it does, but one more question.. how do I add content type and Allow-Cross-Origin-Header to the newjson

Comment: @CharlesFeltman Sorry for the late response! I presume you want to put the headers returned from express into newJSON right? In order to get headers from an express request you can use `req.header("headerNameHere")`, so in order to add those headers you'd add something like `"Content-Type": req.header("Content-Type"),` after `"type": total,` and then doing the same after that replacing `Content-Type` with `Allow-Cross-Origin-Header`.

Comment: Okay, I'll add those items and thanks for the help!